# NodeJS - mssql - Turkish character problem during recording

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server

I can get the data from the request properly on the console screen, it records the characters missing when I want to record.

https://i.hizliresim.com/Vwf1LC.jpg

```
request
    .input('ADI', sql.VarChar, data.ADI)
    .input('SOYADI', sql.Text, data.SOYADI)
    .input('PASSWORD', sql.VarChar, data.PASSWORD)
    .input('EMAIL', sql.VarChar, data.EMAIL)
    .input('GSM_TELEFON', sql.VarChar, data.GSM_TELEFON)

    .query("INSERT INTO TBL_KULLANICILAR ( ADI, SOYADI, PASSWORD, EMAIL, GSM_TELEFON, SYSTEM_REGISTER_DATE, ACTIVE ) VALUES ( @ADI, @SOYADI, @PASSWORD, @EMAIL, @GSM_TELEFON, GETDATE(), 1)", function(err,recordSet) {
        if(err) {
            callback(err)
            sql.close();
        } else {
            callback(recordSet)
            sql.close();
        }

    });
```

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: @Larnu I cannot save the Turkish character in the database.

Comment: You're using `varchar` according to your code. That's the problem.